# SVN: status of svn import

Tags: svn, cmd

in my PHP-Script I create folders and files locally which I want to put in my SVN. I use a .cmd-file containing `svn import PATH/TO/MY/FOLDERS/AND/FILES`, which works without problem.
After the svn import was successfull, I want to delete the folders I just put into SVN locally with the same .cmd-script. So I have to say something like (pseudocode) 
`if(svn import PATH/TO/FOLDERS == successful){delete PATH/TO/FOLDERS locally}`
Is such a thing even possible? I don't know much about .cmd-scripting, so please forgive my question if it is stupid.

Answer (score 0):

SVN import will return 0 if successful, and non-zero on error. A POSIX compliant shell will be able to interpret this so that you can write something like `svn import PATH/TO/FOLDERS && rm -rf /PATH/TO/FOLDERS`.

PHP's system() function takes a second argument -- a return value, which will be set when system() is called:

```
$svncmd = 'svn import PATH/TO/FOLDERS'
system( $svncmd, $retval);
if( $retval != 0 ) {
    $rmcmd = 'rm -rf PATH/TO/FOLDERS'
    system( $rmcmd, $retval);
    if( $retval != 0 ) {
         echo '"' . $rmcmd . '" failed and returned '"' . $retval . '"';
    }
} else {
    echo '"' . $svncmd . '" failed and returned '"' . $retval . '"';
}
```

I think that I would be inclined to wrap the call to `system()` and the following error message inside a function, to make the code more concise.

Perl has a special value called `$!` which contains the text of any error message returned by `system()` or its relatives. I'm sure that PHP has something similar, but my 5 seconds worth of googling didn't find anything. It's well worth looking this up; it will make your error messages far more readable.

It's also worth noting that using system() makes your code inherently non-portable. Probably better to use [PHP's SVN functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.svn.php).

Comment: Ah yes, I see.
However, I use PHP just to create the .cmd-script, so I have to check in the .cmd-script (if even possible!) if svn import was successful.
When I start the .cmd (using Windows here) it is printed that all files were commited successfully to my SVN, but is there a way to check this with some code?
So a user doesn't have to look if svn import was successfull and delete the local folder manually.